# Druid lookups one-to-many

Tags: druid

I have a troubles with creating a lookups. I want to map for example , `key: 'test'` to multiple dimension values for example `data.page.href` or `data.app-id`. In documentation i read that is possible but there is no examples how to do that. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Can you share more details? Can you share your exact query?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible.

On [this](http://druid.io/docs/latest/querying/lookups.html) link it also says:

> It is worth noting that lookups support not just use cases where keys map one-to-one to unique values, such as country code and country name, but also support use cases where multiple IDs map to the same value, e.g. multiple app-ids mapping to a single account manager.

So you cannot have 1 key `test` linking to multiple values. However, you can have multiple keys like `test1` and `test2` which both resolve to the same value `data.page.href`.